# Trying to move words from dictionary using grep command to append .txt file

Tags: linux, bash, files, grep, output

Doing a project going for extra credit by making script to do work for me instead of me typing in commands over and over.
I need to move several words from a file. Not just the words, but words including them like Lan would get WLan ect..
Made a script instead of just typing in commands to save time.
so far script goes.

```
#!/bin/bash

grep ["LAN" /usr/share/dict/words] >> jputn003.txt
```

square brackets aren't working but without some sort of bracket the output to file is every word instead of only the ones including LAN. I figure it needs some sort of bracket to tell it to do grep first and I might just have them in the wrong place.
Please give me some pointers...

Answer (score 1):

You keep *appending* to the jputn003.txt file (with the `>>` redirection). Since it contains bad data, delete it and run your script again.

---

Old answer follows:

I'm assuming that you do not have an environment by the name of `LAN`.

```bsh
grep "$LAN" /usr/share/dict/words
```

Because the first argument is in double quotes, it is subject to [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).
The bash shell will substitute the variable $LAN. Since it is not set to any value, the shell substitutes an empty string. Now we have:

```bsh
grep "" /usr/share/dict/words
```

grep is being asked to output which lines of the file contain an empty string. They all do.